# Caret package in R - get top Variable of Importance

Tags: r, caret

I am facing two problems while using `caret` package in R. I am reproducing an example below:

```
library(mlbench)
library(caret)
set.seed(998)

data(Sonar)   #Random data, just for illustration purpose
Sonar= Sonar[, 1:6] #Selected first 6 columsn only for showing an example. I am assuming V6 to be response.
head(Sonar)
inTraining <- createDataPartition(Sonar$V6, p = 0.75, list = FALSE)
training <- Sonar[inTraining, ]
testing <- Sonar[-inTraining, ]
modelFit <- train( V6~.,data=training, method="rpart" )  
varImp(modelFit)
```

a. How to extract top three (3) variables from `varImp` output? I tried to order the variables but for any reason, its not working for me.

b. Also, why the following code doesn't work for "randomForest"?

```
modelFit <- train( V6~.,data=training, method="rf" )  
varImp(modelFit)


> varImp(modelFit)

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in varImp[, "%IncMSE"] : subscript out of bounds
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What is the issue with #1? It runs fine for me and the result of the call to varImp() produces the following, ordered most to least important:

```
> varImp(modelFit)
rpart variable importance

   Overall
V5 100.000
V4  38.390
V3  38.362
V2   5.581
V1   0.000
```

**EDIT Based on Question clarification:**

I am sure there are better ways, but here is how I might do it:

```
ImpMeasure<-data.frame(varImp(modelFit)$importance)
    ImpMeasure$Vars<-row.names(ImpMeasure)
ImpMeasure[order(-ImpMeasure$Overall),][1:3,]
```

Regarding #2, you need to add importance=TRUE in order to tell `randomForest` to calculate them.

```
> modelFit <- train( V6~.,data=training, method="rf" ,importance = TRUE)
> varImp(modelFit)
rf variable importance

   Overall
V5 100.000
V3  22.746
V2  21.136
V4   3.797
V1   0.000
```

Comment: I just need to extract the top three variables. In this example,  `V5, V4 and V3`

Comment: Edited response

Comment: Note `varImp(modelFit)` won't work if you want to export directly to file. You'll need to convert to a dataframe and add the variable names like either above or Scott's dplyr answer below

Answer (score 4):

Below is a dplyr option using pipes. It does seems strange that this is so hard to access.

```
library(dplyr)

col_index <- varImp(modelFit)$importance %>% 
  mutate(names=row.names(.)) %>%
  arrange(-Overall)
```

If you want the top three, then this should work:

```
imp_names <- col_index$names[1:3]
```

You can also subset the original data frame like this:

```
Sonar_imp <- Sonar[,imp_names]
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick:

```
rownames(varImp(modelFit)$importance)[1:3]
```

Comment: without sorting, this just gives the first three variable namesn V1, V2, V3